# IAuthProvider for OAuth2 in ServiceStack

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, servicestack

Can anyone provide an example of how to implement IAuthProvider against an OAuth2 endpoint in ServiceStack? As far as I can see all the AuthProvider implementations I can find (like Facebook/Google) are using OpenID or OAuth v1.